# where to get crystal reports 13 merge modules for visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, crystal-reports, installshield-le

I have a .NET windows forms application that uses crystal reports 13, I want to package the application with Installshield LE, however I cannot find the crystal reports merge modules neither on SAP's website or anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Not too hard to google for really, https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Crystal+Reports%2C+Developer+for+Visual+Studio+Downloads

Found in about 2 minutes.

Comment: yeah found it in 1, doesn't contain the merge modules only the runtime.

Answer (score 0):

OK after giving up I downloaded the latest version of CR and the merge modules, I had to recreate the reports however to solve multiple dependency errors but it worked eventually.